# How do I write my SQL Order By to follow the arrangement in the IN parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to have the ORDER BY in my SQL follow the arrangement based on the WHERE IN parameters. Here's my current SQL

```
SELECT a.code, a.name 
FROM sometable a 
WHERE a.code IN ('D001sa', 'EX!5', 'A$34')
```

The result I need to get is:

```
a.code      a.name
--------------------
'D001sa'    Home
'EX!5'      Family
'A$34'      Green
```

If I have either `ORDER BY a.code` or `a.name`, I don't get the results I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using `values()`:

```
SELECT a.code, a.name 
FROM sometable a JOIN
     (VALUES ('D001sa', 1), ('EX!5', 2), ('A$34', 3)
     ) v(code, ord)
     ON a.code = v.code
ORDER BY ord;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Much obliged for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

You can use values as stated earlier or INNER JOIN a compound UNION query.

```
SELECT a.code, a.name FROM sometable st
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT code = 'D001sa', order = 1
   UNION
   SELECT code = 'EX!5', order = 2
   UNION
   SELECT code = 'A$34', order = 3
)AS X ON x.code=st.code
ORDER BY
    X.order
```